# Monotouch MTSplitViewController deselect row

Tags: xamarin.ios

I've replaced UISplitViewController with MTSplitViewController, works very nice except one issue.

On master view I've navigation controller and once selected I want that row to remain selected e.g in blue color so user can see current item detail view belongs to.

I could do this easily with Apple's UISplitViewController by overriding Selected method and not doing base.Selected if iPad:

```
        public override void Selected (DialogViewController dvc, UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (AppDelegate.IsPhone) 
            base.Selected (dvc, tableView, indexPath);
    }
```

For some reason same code doesn't work with MTSplitViewController and I've no idea why. I've studied it's code, but don't see why it does this.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only took me half a day to find out what's going on, so hopefully it will save someone else time :)

In your master view set:

```
ClearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false;
```

Found this when you create Master/Detail project in Xcode.